# how is array and array[:] making a difference in the following algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

In the following algorithm when I am using permutation.append(array) in base case it just copies around the same thing. But when I try array[:] which I think is the same thing it works correctly. I am not sure for the reason. Can someone explain what's going on

```
def getPermutations(array):
        # Write yor code here.
        permutation=[]
        perm(0, array, permutation)
        print(permutation)
        return permutation
    
    
    def perm(i, array, permutation):
        if i==len(array)-1:
            print(array)
            permutation.append(array)
            print(permutation)
        else:
            for j in range(i, len(array)):
                swap(array,i,j)
                perm(i+1, array, permutation)
                swap(array,i,j)
    
    def swap(array, i, j):
        array[i], array[j]=array[j], array[i]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: The short answer is that using the array variable name as is only copies the reference to the array, such that any changes you'll make (adding/deleting elements) will be applied on the same array of the caller function, while the `[:]` operation creates a new copy of the array, such that the adding/deleting operations won't be applied on the caller's array. The elements themselves, however, may still be shared between the two arrays, since the copy is shallow, so changing an element's attribute in one array may be reflected on the other array too (irrelevant for immutable objects).

Comment: `array[:]` creates a *copy* of the list. If you don't do that, then no copy is made.

Comment: @SomethingSomething it's best not to say that `array` makes *any copy at all*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you can sometimes say that sending a variable by reference is just like sending a pointer/reference by value :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array[:]` shallow-copies the current array whereas `array` is a **reference** to **the** array object itself. To visualize, when you use `permutation.append(array)`, your list can be visualized like this:
[image]

If you use `permutation.append(array[:])`, your list will be like this:

[image]
Difference between `shallow-copy` and `deep-copy`:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Notice that since our array consists of immutable data types, there is no difference in this case between deep and shallow copy. You just create the copy of the array.

##### Extra

To better explain the difference between a copy and the original object, please inspect the code below carefully.

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a_copy = a   # a_copy refers to the same object as a  (array case)
b_copy = a[:] # b_copy refers to the copy of the a (array[:] case)
a_copy.append(8)
print(a_copy)
print(b_copy)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  # a_copy
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]     # b_copy
```

Comment: I'd call the "primitive" data types "immutable", since there aren't really primitives in Python, even float and int are objects that are stored on the heap, they're just immutable.  When you write `a = 0` and then `a += 1`, you don't really increment existing integer variable - what really happens is that a new integer is created on the heap and `a` is assigned with its new reference. Same for str, float, etc.